# A simple "for loop" doesnt work - django

Tags: django

When i do a simple code in django, its just shows me the next messege:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[0,1,2]' from '[0,1,2]'
```

And there is the code:

```
                    {% for i in [0,1,2] %}
                        <div class="coverw-block-welcome">
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

The smae thing if i do "range".
For some reason django dont let me using "for loop".
Its a problem with django

Answer (score 1):

Django template language is not Python, it does not support lists.

In your case, you can loop over the characters of a string:

```
{% for i in "012" %}
```